# Is it possible to populate the quickfix list with the errors of vimscript functions?

Tags: vimscript

I often write functions in my `~/.vimrc` or in `~/.vim/autoload/myfunctions.vim`, which when executed result in an error such as:

```
Error detected while processing function SomeFunction:
line   xx:
```

Those errors can be read in the output of the Ex command `:messages`.
Is there a way to populate the quickfix list with them, so that I can type `:copen`, navigate through them, hit `Enter` on one, and be automatically redirected to the file and line where an error has been raised?

Comment: it should be possible to set the 'errorformat' to the required formatstring, redir the messages command to a temporary file and use :cfile to read and parse the file into a quickfix list. I have never done that however

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I thought about doing something like this but I don't know all the details of `:help error-file-format`. That's the solution that I would like the most. If one day I know how to do it, I'll post it here. Thank you for pointing me on the right direction (`'errorformat'`) and confirming it's possible.

Comment: Yeah, errorformat is a little bit like black vodoo ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [recent question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34078655/15934) inspired me to develop a [function that decodes `v:throwpoint`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/exception.vim) that I use in a new [logger](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/commit/268a18a5c9af7e5f411934a67f29e15ce0bbed8f) that fills the quickfix list, and [my unit testing framework for vim](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-UT).

This can be used to enhance romainl's answer in order to decode file+line from error messages.

```
function! Bar() abort
    bar
endfunction

function! Foo()
  try
    call Bar()
  catch /.*/
    let bt = lh#exception#callstack(v:throwpoint)
    let data = map(copy(bt), '{"filename": v:val.script, "text": "called from here", "lnum": v:val.pos}')
    let data[0].text = v:exception
    call setqflist(data)
  endtry
endfunction
```

Since my initial answer, I've [improved the workflow](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Callstack.md#lhexceptionsay_what) to be able to decode the last error(s) sent as messages. A typical way to use it would be through a command like the following

```
command! -nargs=? WTF call lh#exception#say_what(<q-args>)
```

Note: my implementation tries to adapt automatically to the current locale (see `:h :lang`...) as error messages are localized, and to support some other minor issue (like `'#'` character not `'isk'` list option).

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a complete solution for you but most complex plugins have some kind of logging function for handling errors in a generic way.

A good approach would be to wrap some or all of your code in a `try-catch` block, parse the exception and populate the quickfix list with useful information.

Here is a very simplistic implementation of the idea:

```
function Foo()
    try
        bar
    catch
        call setqflist([{"bufnr":1,"lnum":1,"text":v:exception}])
    endtry
 endfunction
```

Pointing to the right file doesn't sound as easy, though.

See `:help setqflist()`, `:help :try`, `:help v:exception`.

Answer (score 4):

[image]I made a Vim plugin which is to jump to Vim script's last error or load errors to current loclist.

https://github.com/rbtnn/vim-vimscript_lasterror

If you would like, you can try it.

Comment: rbtnn, welcome to [vi.se]! Btw, I noticed another account with the same name submitted an edit to your answer. Do you need a mod to merge the accounts (are they the same person)?

Answer (score 3):

I've taken the liberty to build on both @romainl and @LucHermite's answers. I define the `Stacktrace` function, which can be called both manually and to get a trace for a specific error.

```
function! MyFunction(...)
  " Stacktrace can be called to get a manual stacktrace
  call Stacktrace()

  " It can also be called to get stacktrace for an error
  try
    " ...
  catch
    call Stacktrace()
  endtry
endfunction

function! Stacktrace()
  "
  " Get stack and exception
  "
  if empty(v:throwpoint)
    try
      throw 'dummy'
    catch
      let l:stack = reverse(split(v:throwpoint, '\.\.'))[1:]
      let l:exception = 'Manual stacktrace'
    endtry
  else
    let l:stack = reverse(split(v:throwpoint, '\.\.'))
    let l:exception = v:exception
  endif

  "
  " Build the quickfix entries
  "
  let l:qflist = []
  let l:files = {}
  for l:func in l:stack
    let [l:name, l:offset] = (l:func =~# '\S\+\[\d')
          \ ? matchlist(l:func, '\(\S\+\)\[\(\d\+\)\]')[1:2]
          \ : matchlist(l:func, '\(\S\+\), line \(\d\+\)')[1:2]

    if l:name =~# '\v(\<SNR\>|^)\d+_'
      let l:sid = matchstr(l:name, '\v(\<SNR\>|^)\zs\d+\ze_')
      let l:name  = substitute(l:name, '\v(\<SNR\>|^)\d+_', 's:', '')
      let l:filename = map(
            \ Command('scriptnames'),
            \ 'split(v:val, "\\v:=\\s+")[1]')[l:sid-1]
    else
      let l:name = l:name
      let l:filename = matchstr(
            \ Command('verbose function ' . l:name)[1],
            \ '.\{-}\s\+\zs\f\+$')
    endif

    let l:filename = fnamemodify(l:filename, ':p')
    if filereadable(l:filename)
      if !has_key(l:files, l:filename)
        let l:files[l:filename] = reverse(readfile(l:filename))
      endif

      let l:lnum = l:offset + len(l:files[l:filename])
            \ - match(l:files[l:filename], '^\s*fu\%[nction]!\=\s\+' . l:name)
      let l:text = len(l:qflist) == 0 ? l:exception : '#' . len(l:qflist)

      call add(l:qflist, {
            \ 'filename': l:filename,
            \ 'lnum': l:lnum,
            \ 'text': l:text,
            \})
    endif
  endfor

  call setqflist(l:qflist)
  execute 'copen' len(l:qflist) + 2
  wincmd p
endfunction

function! Command(cmd)
  let l:a = @a
  try
    silent! redir @a
    silent! execute a:cmd
    redir END
  finally
    let l:res = @a
    let @a = l:a
    return split(l:res, "\n")
  endtry
endfunction
```