# How to identify the script that's calling a user command?

Tags: vimscript, sessions, command

I have a problem: I need to pass « any » caller-**session** trace into a user command… Was trying with:

```
command WantToKnowWhosCalling call Impl("\<SID>",
    \ expand("<SID>"), eval('expand("<SID>")'),
    \ expand('<sfile>'))
```

all methods were failing — `<SID>` because it's fixed-straight (it's almost like if Bram was brushing some potential security issues…) to point to the «**command-defining**» session. **`<sfile>`** was ·*almost*· there, however… It returns the script-file path (a very good ID…) only at the time of the `:source`, later, when expanded from the script-defined functions, it's **≈ `<stack>`**…

Has someone any more ideas? I need to: « **identify the command-caller** », basically… It can be a random-ID, but stable-assigned and unique. The goal is to know that it's a « client script-**A** *returning* », i.e.: recognized and associated with its previous calls to the custom `:Command`.

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly. Are you looking for `expand('<SID>')` (needs patch 8.2.1347)?

Comment: As I IMHO clearly described, `expand('<SID>')` on the RHS of a `:command`-def returns the `<SID>` of the **command's owning script**, not of the script where the user-command is called.

Answer (score 1):

By throwing an exception you should be able to obtain the full (functions) callstack. I've described part the process in a [section of the documentation of my library plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Callstack.md) along with the related functions I provide to decode `v:throwpoint`. IIRC, there is another Q/A where I delved more in details about how its works... Found [it](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25936/getting-the-line-number-and-function-name-of-a-function-caller)! And also [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6019/is-it-possible-to-populate-the-quickfix-list-with-the-errors-of-vimscript-functi).

There are a few limitations: it only returns calling functions. If your function is called only through commands or mappings, you won't see anything useful. It's also extremely slow: do not abuse of the feature.

EDIT: it seems that `v:throwpoint` and Vim 8.2.1297 `expand('<stack>')` return a string (almost) in the same format. Split it at `..`. Then each element will contain a function name (and may a line number). From there the best way to know where it's defined is with `verbose function {funcname}`. The difficulty is that the message will be localized, and sometimes anonymous functions have already been garbage collected (or why I don't use them any more).

My library already takes care of all these issues. I'll eventually upgrade it to use `expand('<stack>')` whenever it's possible as I expect better performances.

Comment: We can get the callstack with `expand('<stack>')` since [8.2.1297](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.1297).

Comment: @user938271 Thanks. This is good to know. As https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1125 hasn't been updated I've missed the information. I see we miss a little bit of information: my API returns the line where callstack request happens, with a little wrapper it should be fine!

Comment: Yes I've already noticed the usefulness of `<stack>`, however in different way — the function call stack isn't a good ID as it fluctuates depending on the call tree… **However** if there is a script-local `s:otherScriptFunction`, then the stack will leak the other's script `<SID>`, because it'll be right there in the function-name as e.g.: `<SNR>112_otherScriptFunction`.

Comment: @Mooncer In lh-vim-lib I've implemented a [way to convert _function -> scriptname_](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/exception.vim#L82) as one of the prime use case of my `lh#exception#...`  functions is to fill the quickfix window.